# IOS:Tabbar issue when clicking tabbar button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I am doing app related to tab bar and navigation bar.

I had 4 tab bar button and  when i clicked in 3rd button in tab-bar view appears fine and when I clicked back button on third view of tab bar its shows home view. i.e first tab bar item up to here is fine and when i click home button and came back to again to third tab bar item.

It shows the home view again instead of third view. Is there any code for this.

Please help me

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
       [self showViewController:self sender:nil];
     }
```

I tried this but getting error "Pushing View Controller more than once is not supported ?"

Comment: "when i clicked back button on the third view of tab bar its shows home view i.e first tab bar item" -- this makes no sense. Clicking a back button should not take you from one tab to another. You need to more fully explain what controllers you have.

Comment: that means your navigation controller is at wrong place... if you click tab, and if you see back button that means something is wrong in ur navigation... show ur screenshot of the IB...